# Binary serialization not working, not valid header

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I got the following, not to comlex code, anyway I get an exception while deserialization.
The exception is: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.

But I don't get what is wrong with my code

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Server
{
    [Serializable]
    class testclass
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        public testclass()
        {
            a = 1;
            b = 2;
            c = 3000;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testclass test = new testclass();
            IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[512],0,512,true,true);
            bf.Serialize(ms,test);
            testclass detest=(testclass)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewind to the start of the stream first after that you can deserialize or read your stream Example: ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testclass test = new testclass();
        IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[512],0,512,true,true);
        bf.Serialize(ms,test);
        ms.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin); //rewinded the stream to the begining.
        testclass detest=(testclass)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: ok not only do i have to rewind the stream, but my message has to start at 0, but I'm still having some issues, I will update my question with some more code

Comment: ok, but if its a new question please post a new one and click answered on the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: ok the last issue was about not knowing my own protocol, so thank you both for pointing out the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your stream is at the end of your data when you do

```
bf.Serialize(ms,test);
```

rewind it to start before trying

```
testclass detest=(testclass)bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

Use `Position=0` on the stream to do it.